# Devexpress SearchLookUpEdit set value from database

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have this code on my Form load for filling my data on my datatable and then populate on my SearchLookupEdit:

```
FillGrids(oData, "POLIST",
    "SELECT [PORecord].[POID],[ItemCode],[PONumber],"
  + "[SiteNo]+' '+[Place]+' '+[Name]+' '+[ScopeOfWork]"
  + "+' '+CAST([DeliveryDate] AS VARCHAR(30))"
  + "+' '+CAST([PRNumber]AS VARCHAR(10))+' '+[Requisitioner] AS Name,"
  + "[UnitPrice],[Quantity],[Unit],Completed,Status"
  + " FROM [Globaltek-Final].[Project].[PORecord]"
  + " INNER JOIN Project.POStatus ON Project.PORecord.POID = Project.POStatus.POID",
  CommandType.Text);

cmbPOID.Properties.DataSource = oData.Tables["POLIST"];
cmbPOID.Properties.DisplayMember = "PONumber";
cmbPOID.Properties.ValueMember = "POID";
```

then by this event:

```
private void cmbPOID_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cmbPOID.ShowPopup();

    System.Data.DataRow row = gvPOID.GetDataRow(gvPOID.FocusedRowHandle);
    try
    {
        oPOID = row[0].ToString();
        txtAmount.Text = row["UnitPrice"].ToString();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I can change value of the control and then add it to my database.

Edit: To load my data which i store in database i use this code:

```
 using (SqlCommand xComm = new SqlCommand())
 {
     xComm.Connection = xConn;
     xComm.CommandText =
        "SELECT [ProjectID] ,[Year] ,[NTPID] ,Project.MainProjectRecord.[POID],"
      + "[SiteID]  ,[SiteName]  ,[SiteDetailsID] ,[EquipmentID]  ,[RepGlobaltekID],"
      + "[CompletedID] ,[OnGoingID]  ,Project.PORecord.POID"
      + " FROM [Globaltek-Final].[Project].[MainProjectRecord]"
      + " INNER JOIN Project.PORecord ON Project.MainProjectRecord.POID = Project.PORecord.POID"
      + " WHERE ProjectID = @recordID";
     xComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     xComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recordID", RecordID);

     SqlDataReader xReader = null;
     try
     {
         xConn.Open();
         xReader = xComm.ExecuteReader();
         while (xReader.Read())
         {
             txtSiteID.Text = xReader["SiteID"].ToString();
             txtSiteName.Text = xReader["SiteName"].ToString();
             cmbPOID.EditValue = xReader["POID"].ToString();
             cmbPOID.Properties.GetDisplayTextByKeyValue(xReader["POID"].ToString());
             //cmbPOID.EditValue = xReader["POID"].ToString();
         }
         xReader.Close();
     }
     .....
```

My problem is how to set or load the value, which I get from database back to the SearchLookupEdit control?

Comment: From what I understand, are you trying to refresh the content of the combobox after you've added a new item to the database?

Comment: No.. supposing i have a form having searchlookupedit for adding a data and also this form will be use for updating data the problem is that i cant find a way to load the data from the database to the searchlookupedit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display value or set a value on a searchlookupedit when binding it into dataset using datatable it should match the searchlookupedit.properties.valuemember to the value you pass into your editvalue something like this..

```
int value= 12;
       searchLookUpEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "POID";
       searchLookUpEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "PONumber";
       searchLookUpEdit1.EditValue = ValueDisplay(); //it should match the value member

 private object ValueDisplay()
    {
        return value;
    }
```

To my problem i fill first the datatable and populate it into the searchloookupedit. when setting the searchlookupedit.editvalue it is blank it is because on my datatable column it is name "PoID" while on my value member it is "POID". This should fix and must be in the same name so that editvalue will effect. i change "POID" --> "PoID". :D

Answer (score 0):

After getting the value of POID of your record, just set the `EditValue` property before the form `ShowDialog` in case you edit the item, to have something like :

```
using(var dlg = new ProjectForm())
{
    dlg.searchLookUp.EditValue = poid;

    dlg.ShowDialog(); //The rest of your code
}
```

And in the load of you form, you should set the DataSource property of the searchLookup. The properties ValueMember and DisplayValue can be set via the designer, even though, I'll set them in the code

```
searchLookup.DataSource = myFunctionToGetData();
searchLookup.Properties.DisplayMember = "PONumber";
searchLookup.Properties.ValueMember= "POID";
```

Comment: It would not goes like that supposing i have a datagrid having a rows of data when im going to edit a row of data i only get the whole row record and then when the form loaded the one that i edit above is the code i use to load the data from database to my controls. I think the editvalue event is the problem here i dont know how

Comment: Are you setting the DataSource, ValueMember, DisplayMember properties of your searchLookup BEFORE setting the EditValue ? doing this, it should work fine.

Comment: Datasource,valuemember and displaymember where set before setting the editvalue. Sorry my bad im not stating it very clear.. on my code above it really works when i call the function where i fetch data from database using sqldatareader and pass that value to the (searchlookupedit)cmbPOID.editvalue problem is it will automatically go the the event editvaluechange which gives an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" im lacking something on the event editvaluechange

Comment: Thanks SidAhmed by reading on your comment it should work fine. But then my bad.. the column name PoID on my datatable didnt match on my searchLookup.Properties.ValueMember= "POID"; thats why editvalue it not in effect... Can i give rep on your comment :D thanks